# File OnChange method when called second time it takes the previous file which is selected first Time

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I am using Eel package of python that help me to integrate Html/CSS/js with python
so I am dynamically generating Html tags via JS based on input in a python file
basically it's a chatbot and UI of that chatbot is created by Html/js

main.js that creates tags dynamically

```
eel.expose(selectPDF);
function selectPDF(moduleSelection){ // moduleSelection is coming from python
    console.log("select pdf called")
    var DemoDom = document.createElement("input");
    DemoDom.setAttribute('type','file'); //creating tag for input file
    DemoDom.setAttribute('name','myfile');
    DemoDom.id = "agenttext";
    DemoDom.setAttribute('class','selectButton');
    DemoDom.setAttribute('multiple','multiple');
    DemoDom.setAttribute('onchange','showname("'+moduleSelection+'")')
    chatBox.appendChild(DemoDom);

}
eel.expose(showname); //this is eel package syntax
function showname(moduleSelection){
    console.log("i am here")
    var name = document.getElementsByClassName('selectButton');
    var fileList = [];
    // if only one file is selected do this
    if(name[0].files.length === 1){
        console.log("File name: ", name[0].files[0].name)
        var temp = name[0].files[0].name;
        eel.getFileName(temp,moduleSelection); // passing file to python function getFileName
    }
    else{
        for (var i = 0; i < name[0].files.length; i++) {
            console.log("File name for loop: ", name[0].files[i].name)
           fileList.push(name[0].files[i].name); // push all file to list 
        }
        eel.getFileName(fileList,moduleSelection); // passing filelist to python function getFileName
    }
    return
}
```

Now when I call selectPDF() first time it creates input tag and call onchange method all working fine

but now When I call it the second time js again create input tag and call onchange method and it takes the previous file and not the new one that I want to select

see the image

[image: Ignore red errors]

**JUST SEE THE FILE NAME: image.png**

**ignore all other red errors**

as you can see in the image when I call "image to text" first time it works fine creates DOM and proceed further but when the second time I call "image to text" it creates DOM but select the previous file image.png instead of Sample.pdf

You can see the console file name
it should select Sample.pdf instead of image.png when calling the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your app executes this code each time

```
if(name[0].files.length === 1){
        console.log("File name: ", name[0].files[0].name)
        var temp = name[0].files[0].name;
        eel.getFileName(temp,moduleSelection); // passing file to python function getFileName
    }
```

#### 1. Index selection

Is there a reason you're selecting the first index from `name[0]` each time? Maybe just checking for `name.files.length` would work?

#### 2. If/else algorithm

If you structure your code a bit better, it might surprisingly work better. Try using the Javascript [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method instead of your loop. It would look something like this

```
function showname(moduleSelection) {
    console.log("i am here");
    var files = document.getElementsByClassName('selectButton');
    
    var fileList = [];
    if (files.length > 0) {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log("File name: ", file.files[0].name);
            fileList.push(file.files[0].name);
        })
        eel.getFileName(fileList, moduleSelection);
    }
    return;
}
```

I hope this will *maybe* ***hopefully*** help!

EDIT:

If u want to remove previous files **after** calling the files, you will have to mark the currently selected files at `document.getElementsByClassName('selectButton')` as **already called**.

You can do this in various way, an example would be to change the **class name** from `selectButton` to `selectButtonDone` after the file name was pushed into the `fileList[]` array.

You can do this particularly by executing `file.className = 'selectButtonDone';` at the end of the `files.forEach()` function.

Comment: after little modification,`Array.from(files).forEach(file => {})` it print **File name:  image.png** and when I call the second time it prints **File name:image.png File name:Sample.pdf** what I need is it should not preserve the previous file which is selected, in our case image.png eg. the first time I called and selected image.png then it should print image.png, and now again I called and selected 2 files foo.pdf and bar.pdf then it should print foo.pdf and bar.pdf **and not the image.png, foo.pdf, bar.pdf** it should not print image.png should not preserve a previous file.Thanks in advance

Comment: Good work on implementing forEach, I hope that solved party of your problem ;)
Try applying my edit as well, maybe that will do your job done

Comment: Your Edit Work Like Charm, But with some modifications, I got what I needed Thanks, you saved my hours.

Comment: Modified Code: 
    `var file = document.getElementsByClassName('selectButton');
    var fileList = [];
    console.log(file[0].files.length)
    if (file[0].files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < file[0].files.length; i++) {
            console.log("File name: ", file[0].files[i].name);
            fileList.push(file[0].files[i].name);
        }
        file[0].className = 'selectButtonDone';
        eel.getFileName(fileList, moduleSelection);
    }`